# Error with new data with same number of predictors but different number of rows when using predict()

Tags: r, prediction, random-forest, gbm

I am trying to run the prediction function I got after training my model and after cross validation. I am predicting the variable "classe."

The test data has the same name number of predictors as the training data, except it has fewer rows (20 observations). All of the predictors in the test data are numeric (just like training data). But it seems like it's causing problems no matter what models I used.

Model:

```
rf <- train(train$classe ~., method="rf", data=train, 
        trControl = trainControl(method = "oob"))
```

I tried:

```
predict(rf, testing1)
```

I got

```
Error in predict.randomForest(modelFit, newdata) : newdata has 0 rows
```

then I tried

```
gbm <- train(train$classe ~., method="gbm", data=train, 
         trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number=5))

predict(gbm, testing1)
```

I got

```
Error in aperm.default(psum, c(2, 1, 3)) : 
'perm' is of wrong length 3 (!= 2)
```

My test data looks like this, the only difference is the last variable indicates a "problem id", whereas in the training set the last variable indicates "classe":

```
> str(testing1)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  86 variables:
 $ roll_belt              : num  123 1.02 0.87 125 1.35 -5.92 1.2 0.43 0.93 114 ...
 $ pitch_belt             : num  27 4.87 1.82 -41.6 3.33 1.59 4.44 4.15 6.72 22.4 ...
 $ total_accel_belt       : num  20 4 5 17 3 4 4 4 4 18 ...
 $ kurtosis_roll_belt     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ kurtosis_picth_belt    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

 ... # all numeric variables 

 $ magnet_forearm_y       : num  419 791 698 783 -787 800 284 -619 652 723 ...
 $ magnet_forearm_z       : num  617 873 783 521 91 884 585 -32 469 512 ...
 $ problem_id             : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem- some of the values in the columns in the test data are "NA" while in the training data they are blank. There were some inconsistencies between how both files are read into R. After fixing that problem, predict() works now.

Answer (score 0):

For predict, I know that the column names have to be the exact same. If even the last one is off, then this can cause problems.